# Writing parallel code using OPENMP

Tags: openmp

Consider the following code segment

```
sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
sum = myfunc(a[i])+ sum;
```

Write the corresponding parallel code segment using OPENMP.

I did this way,

```
sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
sum = myfunc(a[i])+ sum;
```

I'm a newcomer in parallel computing. Do you think is it correct?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately nobody can help you if all you have is "I want to do X" - you need to also show us what you've got and tell us exactly what's not working. If all you have is specifications and a todo list, ... good luck!

Comment: @WorkSmarter, it would have been simpler to write `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)` and the the OP figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum variable will become a point of contention because every iteration touches it. Since you are doing a reduction, you should use the reduction clause to let OpenMP know that you want that variable accumulated across all threads:

```
sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : sum)
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  sum = myfunc(a[i])+ sum;
```